# System.Management.ManagementException: "Privilege not held." When trying to Shutdown Windows 7 in C# 4.0 using WMI

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, wmi

I have a program with some legacy code that does the following to shutdown windows:

```
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass( "Win32_OperatingSystem" );

mc.Get();

mc.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
ManagementBaseObject mboShutdown = mc.GetMethodParameters( "Win32Shutdown" );

mboShutdown["Flags"] = "5"; // shutdown + force
mboShutdown["Reserved"] = "0";

foreach( ManagementObject mbo in mc.GetInstances() )
{
    mbo.InvokeMethod( "Win32Shutdown", mboShutdown, null );
}
```

It was a .NET 3.5 application, and it was working without a problem.  Recently, a dependency upgrade required bumping the target framework to 4.0 client profile.  Now, whenever the code runs, I am getting the following exception:

```
System.Management.ManagementException: "Privilege not held."
```

The application is running under an Admin account on Windows 7, and nothing has changed other than updating this software.

The only information I have been able to find while searching for a solution was some very old bug reports about .NET 1.1, and the following thread on msdn that was never answered:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fa0bcae5-6f30-42b6-bb5f-b8a6edb88ac4/encountered-privillege-not-held-exception-when-rebooting-the-server-in-net40-framewrk

Does anyone know what the cause of this issue is?  Do I need to stop using WMI and just PInvoke InitiateSystemShutdownEx or something similar?

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will help.

Comment: Can you execute using `right-click`- `run as Administrator`

Comment: Arshad, I tried that, there was no change.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so it probably has to do with SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege.  I'm not sure why it was working under .NET 3.5 and not .NET 4.0, but the following workaround works:

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1 )]
internal struct TokPriv1Luid
{
    public int Count;
    public long Luid;
    public int Attr;
}

[DllImport( "kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true )]
internal static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

[DllImport( "advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true )]
internal static extern bool OpenProcessToken( IntPtr h, int acc, ref IntPtr phtok );

[DllImport( "advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true )]
internal static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue( string host, string name, ref long pluid );

[DllImport( "advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true )]
internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges( IntPtr htok, bool disall, ref TokPriv1Luid newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen );

[DllImport( "user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true )]
internal static extern bool ExitWindowsEx( int flg, int rea );

public const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
public const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
public const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;
public const string SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME = "SeShutdownPrivilege";
public const int EWX_LOGOFF = 0x00000000;
public const int EWX_SHUTDOWN = 0x00000001;
public const int EWX_REBOOT = 0x00000002;
public const int EWX_FORCE = 0x00000004;
public const int EWX_POWEROFF = 0x00000008;
public const int EWX_FORCEIFHUNG = 0x00000010;


public static bool DoExitWin( int flg )
{
    TokPriv1Luid tp;
    var hproc = GetCurrentProcess();
    var htok = IntPtr.Zero;
    OpenProcessToken( hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok );
    tp.Count = 1;
    tp.Luid = 0;
    tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    LookupPrivilegeValue( null, SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, ref tp.Luid );
    AdjustTokenPrivileges( htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero );

    return ExitWindowsEx( flg, 0 );
}
```

I haven't tried, but my guess is that the WMI call might work after using the AdjustTokenPrivileges call as well.

Comment: You were correct on your original assumption regarding SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME.  Check out this [link](http://ithoughthecamewithyou.com/post/reboot-computer-in-c-net).

It has the WMI bits to enable the privilege.  The original WMI shutdown method you posted is still much preferred as it forces the shutdown even if the user has unsaved work.

Answer (score 0):

After you apply the April 2017 security updates described in Microsoft security update guidance [CVE-2017-0160](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2017-0160), the PowerShell v3.0+ stop-computer command fails. Additionally, if applications use power management methods, such as shutdown or reboot, from the [Win32_OperatingSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-operatingsystem-methods) class and set the EnablePrivileges attribute to true, they may observe the same failure. A "Privilege not held" error message is returned.

Customer applications using power management methods, such as shutdown or reboot, from the `Win32_OperatingSystem` class and set the `EnablePrivileges` attribute to `true`, may observe the same “Privilege not held” error.

Example 2 (C# code) returns “Privilege not held” error:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ManagementClass mgmtObject = new ManagementClass("Win32_OperatingSystem");
    foreach (ManagementObject iterMgmtObject in mgmtObject.GetInstances())
    {
        iterMgmtObject.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
        iterMgmtObject.InvokeMethod("Reboot", null, null);
    }
}
```

To resolve this problem, install the update your system. More in the [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4020459/privilege-not-held-error-with-powershell-stop-computer-command-and-pow).